# Tracking Form Submit using Google Analytics and Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, forms, goal-tracking

I've set a Google Tag Manager for tracking my website form, I know its working because I saw it on the preview. I've tried to create a conversion goal for track the form submitting but I don't find it out. How can I track the conversion rate and how many users are submitting it with my google analytics?

I can see the conversions on the real time tab.

Comment: What do you see in the preview?  Is it an event or a pageview?   If this is all pageview based, it sounds like a case for funnels, however funnels don't work with events.

Comment: Nevermind, today I found it, still don't know why didn't working yesterday. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate it is working today with no changes.